# QGIS clip raster by mask layer: gdalwarp failed to start

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdalwarp

I run into an error when I try to clip the land cover raster layer from ESA named *ESACCI-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2015-v2.0.7* for the Netherlands. I do this by saving the Netherlands polygon from the world map as a separate layer named *landcover_Netherlands*, then using it in the *raster > Extraction > Clip raster by mask layer*, after which I have to run through the GDALwarp process to get a clipped raster layer of my chosen country.

`Process gdalwarp failed to start. Either gdalwarp is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to run the program.`

I run QGIS (v3.22.11) on a virtual desktop (Citrix), but none of the error options make sense to me, as the virtual desktop QGIS has no restrictions and GDAL is in place (v3.5.1). Am I missing something here? The complete log is as follows:

```
QGIS version: 3.22.11-Białowieża
QGIS code revision: 106d33d7
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.5.1
GEOS version: 3.10.3-CAPI-1.16.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.1.0, September 1st, 2022
PDAL version: 2.4.3 (git-version: 6311a6)
Algorithm started at: 2023-07-04T15:01:09
Algorithm 'Clip raster by mask layer' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ALPHA_BAND' : False, 'CROP_TO_CUTLINE' : True, 'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : 'L:/Temp/ESACCI-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2015-v2.0.7.tif', 'KEEP_RESOLUTION' : False, 'MASK' : 'U:\\My Documents\\LCS VENV\\Tutorial 3\\1. Backboard import IMP\\landcover_Netherlands.gpkg|layername=landcover_Netherlands', 'MULTITHREADING' : False, 'NODATA' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'SET_RESOLUTION' : False, 'SOURCE_CRS' : None, 'TARGET_CRS' : None, 'X_RESOLUTION' : None, 'Y_RESOLUTION' : None }

GDAL command:
gdalwarp -overwrite -of GTiff -cutline "U:\\My Documents\\LCS VENV\\Tutorial 3\\1. Backboard import IMP\\landcover_Netherlands.gpkg" -cl landcover_Netherlands -crop_to_cutline L:/Temp/ESACCI-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2015-v2.0.7.tif C:/Users/[omitted]/AppData/Local/Temp/2/processing_ZqhulU/f892294ca23e4f96ac21bf5508f6dffc/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:
Process gdalwarp failed to start. Either gdalwarp is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to run the program.
Execution failed after 0.03 seconds

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Clip raster by mask layer' finished
```